# Is one hot encoding required for this data set?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, one-hot-encoding

Below is the data set from the UCI data repository. I want to build a regression model taking platelets count as the dependent variable(y) and the rest as features/inputs.

[image: Heart_failure data set from UCI repository]

However, there are few categorical variables like such as anemia, sex, smoking, and DEATH_EVENT in the data set in numeric form.

My questions are:

1. Should I perform 'one-hot encoding' on these variables before building a regression model?
2. Also, I observe the values are in various ranges, so should I even scale the data set before applying the regression model?

Comment: From your data sample it looks like there's only the values 0 and 1 for anaemia, sex and smoking. If this is the case, you don't have to perform one-hot encoding.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.Should I perform 'one-hot encoding' on these variables before building a regression model?

Yup, you should one-hot encode the categorical variables. You can use like below:

```
columns_to_category = ['sex', 'smoking','DEATH_EVENT']
df[columns_to_category] = df[columns_to_category].astype('category') # change datetypes to category
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=columns_to_category) # One hot encoding the categories
```

> 2.If so, only one hot encoding is sufficient or should I perform even
> label encoding?

One hot encoding should be sufficient I guess.

> 3.Also, I observe the values are in various ranges, so should I even scale the data set before applying the regression model?

Yes you can use either `StandardScaler()` or `MinMaxScaler()` to get better results and then inverse scale the predictions. Also, make sure you scale the test and train separately and not combined because in real life your test will be not realized so yo need to scale accordingly to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 1):

If those are truly binary categories, you don't have to one hot encode. They are already encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use one-hot encoding as those columns already have numerical values. Although if those numerical values are actually string instead of int or float then you should use one-hot encoding on them. About scaling the data, the variation is considerable, so you should scale it to avoid your regression model being biased towards high values.

Comment: In my view, one-hot encoding is necessary here even though those columns are numerical because the numerical value does not represent any information (1 and 0 just a class variation only and do not mean anything).So if the value does not mean much then the predictor will not really make use of it .

Comment: They are actually representing if  a person has anemia or not, or person has diabetes or not, if a person smokes or not and so on & so forth. Those columns are already encoded. What the get_dummies function  does is it assigns a binary 0,1 value to the categorical string data. It encodes categorical string values into binary values. When the values are already binary encoded, it's not-useful to use one-hot encoding. As i mentioned, it should be encoded if those numerical values are in fact string. Although to do it still, won't do any bad, it's just not required there.